# h1 modification with javascript - is it worth doing for seo

Tags: seo

My online store script on category pages pulls h1 tags form category names. Thats not always what I'd want them to be. Is it worth changing with javascript or google just won't read the altered versions of them and seo won't be affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will read the altered versions of the h1 tag and seo will be affected.